# Removing a row that contains a negative float in a numpy aray

Tags: python, numpy, negative-number

I have a numpy array consisting of 3 columns and there is one value in a column that has a negative value. I need to remove the whole row that contains this value as it corresponds to an anomalous result.

The numpy array looks a little like this:

```py
[[98.4, 0.236, 0.0925]

 [95.2, -0.162, 0.0625]

 [92.3, 0.112, 0.0526]]
```

How would I go about removing the whole row that contains the negative value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index with a boolean mask:

```py
result = array[(array >= 0).all(axis=1)]
```